# Is it possible to create an openGL subwindow with window forms as its parent?

Tags: c#, opengl, glut

I am trying to make an openGL window a child to my windows forms application.

This is the creation of the windows forms which happens by default in the Form1.Designer.cs

```
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaptionText;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1333, 594);
        this.Controls.Add(this.Sim);
        this.Controls.Add(this.Camera);
        this.Controls.Add(this.comboBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)
        (this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
```

Glut.glutcreateSubWindow(int win, int x, int y, int width, int height);

The glutcreateSubWindow takes the parent value as an int and I am having a hard time trying to convert this.Name = "Form1"; to an int that I can use to refer the name of the form as the parent.

I can be out on the blue here and doing this the wrong way by trying to convert the string name to the specified parent slot.

Is there another way to specify the form as the parent in this context?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you should not try to convert "Form 1" to an int, the integer the framework expects there is a GLUT window identifier, you should havfe retrieved and stored one when you create a GLUT top level window, and then you can creat a subwindow of it.

see this article and scroll down to see clear explanation of all the code, it shows you all steps you need to implement: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20107/GLUT-Subwindow-Template

Comment: Is there any possibility to make a GLUT top-level window to a child for the windows forms? I have read about Control.Handle Properties but I cannot seem to understand how I would implement this for it to work for my created glut window

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with glut, but I may know a different approach that might do the trick.

To make a Windows.Forms.Form a parent you will need a Child that is also a System.Windows.Forms.Form (or implement a subclass).

In the past I needed at DirectX overlay in a windows form. And because this is a different API I couldn't add this to a Windows.Forms.Form.

I solved this by implementing a System.Windows.Forms.UserControl (you could implement a System.Windows.Forms.Form or add your custom control to it)
When the control was initialized I Created the Overlay on top of it (you know the corners of your control or window)

So basically I had an empty windows control with a DirectX window on top of it, that followed the control and resized with it (int the resize and move events of the control I changed, or reconstructed my overlay to move with it.)

You could do the same, make a windows.from that has a border less (no title bar) glut window on top that reacts to the Windows.Forms Events.

This is only possible if you can make a border less  Window in Glut, or draw in a kind of rectangular overlay on screen. I don't know if this is possible with Glut.

If this answer isn't helpful in your situation, please tell me and I will delete this answer. I'm just trying to offer a workaround because I've had a similar problem in the past.